# Adding variables not working out

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script type="text/javascript">

function funky(buttonElement){
    var buttonClickedId = buttonElement.id;
    var txt = document.getElementById("id");
    var total1 = txt.value*10;
    var total2 = txt.value*20;
    var total3 = txt.value*30;
    var total4 = // I want to add alt1+alt2+alt3 here.


    if(buttonClickedId === 'min1'){
    document.getElementById("alt1").innerHTML =total1;
    }
    if(buttonClickedId === 'min2'){
    document.getElementById("alt2").innerHTML =total2;
    }
    if(buttonClickedId === 'min3'){
    document.getElementById("alt3").innerHTML =total3;
    }
    if(buttonClickedId === 'abs'){  
    document.getElementById("alt4").innerHTML =total4;
    }
}



</script>

</head>
<body>

<input id="id" type="text" name="asd"><br>
    <button id="min1" onclick="funky(this)">Banan</button>
    <button id="min2" onclick="funky(this)">Eple</button>
    <button id="min3" onclick="funky(this)">Appelsin</button>
    <button id="abs" onclick="funky(this)">Totalt</button>
    <p id="alt1"></p><br>
    <p id="alt2"></p><br>
    <p id="alt3"></p><br>
    <p id="alt4"></p><br>


</body>
</html>
```

I want total4 to add total1+total2+total3. Simply typing total1.value + total2.value  etc works but that does not work when the txt.value is different.

The website wants me to add more context but I do not know of any more valuable context to give. If anyone at all wants to help me and needs more info please ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something here, but why do you have to make total4 equal to total1.value + total2.value + total3.value? Wouldn't simply writing total4 = total1 + total2 + total3 work as well? Why do you need the " .value"  after every variable?

Comment: Yeah sorry, im fairly new, I'm not sure about the difference yet. But that was just an example of how i do not want it done, because that wouldn't work regardless of the ".value" or no ".value".

Comment: What do you mean when you say it wouldn't work regardless of the .value portion?

Comment: For instance if the text value is 10, then i click the "Banan" button and then change the text value to 20 and then click the "Eple" button, the total (total4) would then show as 20*10 + 20*20 = 600, instead of 10*10 + 20*20  = 500 as i want it to